# How to fix: disabling size classes in Xcode 6.2 trashes storyboard UI but keeps guides

Tags: ios8, xcode6

[EDITED] After spending a couple of days on a iPad app (utility s/w for myself; not for release), I accidentally clicked on disabling size classes in Xcode (6.2). I only want to turn off Auto Layout temporarily so I could figure out why my popover scene was not rendering.

Now, all the UI elements are gone but the guidelines for both the main scene and the popover scene are still around. History seemingly shows nothing that will bring back the UI elements. I closed the Xcode project and opened it again, but only the red guidelines are visible.

Has anyone run into this? Any idea how to fix this? [EDIT] I'm referring specifically to the UI elements and getting them all back -- else I'm going to have to spend a couple of hours reconstructing and positioning them. I browsed StackOverflow and Google Search but I've not seen any relevant suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

First, when disabling auto layout it will disable the size classes as well. 
I would suggest that you **update** your Xcode to 6.3. Then that will probably be gone.

Hope that helps :)

**Edit** 
*regarding the comment*

First off I would print the frames of the UIElements to see whether they are still on the screen. (Using `println("(button.frame)")
Then, if they are not there, change their **frames** / centres) to somewhere on the screen. 
If they are in the bounds, check their **sizes** to make sure they are large enough to be visible. If they are then make sure they are not **hidden** and their **alpha** is 1. 
In **storyboard** you can open the side-bar and then change the element's position in the **Attributes inspector** as shown here:

1. [image: step 1]
2. [image: step2]

Comment: Thanks but I don't care about the auto layout or size classes. I'm asking can I get back my UI elements. I'll update my question to be more clear. I don't recall seeing this behavior in Xcode 5, and it just seems crazy that Xcode would trash my entire interface without UNDO capability.

Comment: They are most definitely gone, at least from what Interface Builder is showing at left in the Document Outline view. The elements in each view controller scene are simply not in the document outlines, not hidden with alpha 0. I'm just trying to figure out (1) why Xcode would have such drastic behavior and (2) if there's a way to get the elements back

Comment: So what about their frame?

Comment: Sorry, did not mean to ignore your effort to answer my question. I've had some other deadlines and could not try. I'll try to apply to your suggestion later this week and respond. Thanks